# Hypothesis testing and equality in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, hypothesis-testing

Let $(P,Q)$ and $(P',Q')$ be pairs of random variables and let $\phi, \phi'$ be the most powerful level $\alpha$ tests between $P$ and $Q$ and between $P'$ and $Q'$, respectively.
Suppose that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ have the same power $1-\beta$ at all levels $\alpha$ for both tests. Can we show that this is equivalent to $P=P'$ and $Q=Q'$ in distribution?

It's easy to show that, if $P=P'$ and $Q=Q'$ i.d., the ROC curves are pointwise equal by the construction of the ROC curve, by which one direction follows.

However, I'm not yet able to show the other direction. Any ideas? Can we perhaps show something even stronger, such as $\mathrm{TV}(P,P') = \mathrm{TV}(Q,Q') = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simple counterexample, suppose $P'$ is the law of $X +1,$ where $X \sim P,$ and similarly $Q'$ is the law of $X+1$, where $X \sim Q$. Then for any test for $P$ v/s $Q,$ we can generate a test for $P'$ v/s $Q'$ by first subtracting $1$ from each data point, and vice versa. This means that the ROC curves for the most powerful tests are equal. But of course $P' \neq P$ and $Q' \neq Q$. Same idea works with $X \mapsto X+1$ replaced by any measurable bijection.

Comment: Good point. One would expect that indistinguishability through testing would be a quite strong type of equivalence, but it seems to be in a way pretty weak. Are you aware of any references?

Comment: For the above, not really, never thought about it before. It may still be the case that the distributions are equal up to some deterministic transformation, but I kind of doubt it from a metric entropy point of view in that the ROC curve is just a curve in $[0,1]^2$, while the set of pairs of probability distrubtions is very large indeed (even on modding out this deterministic equivalence), so I'd be surprised if a ROC curve is enough to characterise all such pairs. Not sure where to go looking for this though.

Comment: Oh I guess another class of counterexamples is where $P,Q$ have disjoint support, and so do $P',Q'$, in which case the most powerful tests for either pair have power $1$ for any $\alpha$, but of course the laws need not have any special relationship between them. This does away with the 'deterministic transformation' critique (but now the ROC curves are kind of trivial).

Comment: That is a valid point, I should have specified mutual absolute continuity. How do you feel about the direction $P=P'$ and $Q=Q'$ in distribution implying equality of the ROC curves pointwise? I got a bit insecure about it because it requires assuming that the quantiles being equal implies that the CDFs are equal too, but I may have missed a special case here as well…

Comment: The ROC curve is a functional of the distributions, so that does follow (by Neyman-Pearson, this is the upper boundary of the region $ \{  (P(L(X) > \tau), Q(L(X) \le \tau) ): \tau \in [-\infty,\infty]\},$ where $L$ is (basically) the likelihood ratio between the laws $P$ and $Q$). This same observation might suggest other, more convincing, counterexamples, it might be worth playing with it.